# Magento 2: How to fetch system config value in an email template

Tags: magento2.3, email-templates, system-config

I am trying to fetch system config value inside an html file for email template. But below code is not working

```
{{config path="design/footer/copyright"}}
```

Can someone suggest if there is another way or syntax to do this?

Comment: I had a problem that some config was not loading when I migrated to 2.3, check email_template and change the template column is_legacy to 1 then test if it loads

Answer (score 0):

Add `{{config path="general/store_information/gst_no"}}` in you email template.

Now Login to admin panel and navigate to System->Permissions->Variables

Click on Add new variable and fill the text box with `general/store_information/gst_no`. Set Is Allowed to yes

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Already tried this. Not working. I think this may be for old version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300308/get-custom-configuration-into-email-template-magento